# I get error message "[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory." even I already have one(The Podfile). How can I fix this?

Tags: ios, swift, terminal, cocoapods, podfile

I did 'pod init' inside my project file then

I have Podfile in my project file. and I updated cocoapods to the latest.

```
jeongseongjun-ui-MacBookPro:Flo chungseongjun$ ls
Flo     Flo.xcodeproj   Podfile
jeongseongjun-ui-MacBookPro:Flo chungseongjun$ pod install
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
```

I keep on get this error messages...plz help...

[image]
here's directory snap!

Comment: What does `cat Podfile` say?

Comment: can you attach directory snap @Chung Seong-jun

Comment: @matt this is the result.

jeongseongjun-ui-MacBookPro:Flo chungseongjun$ cat Podfile
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Flo' do
  
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'

end

Comment: @VinodKumar Ive attached it!

Comment: Actually the irony here is that you probably do not need SwiftyJSON. You should be using built-in Codable instead.

Comment: @matt Actually I knew I dont have to use that one but the important thing is the other cocoapods dont work including SwiftyJSON :( but still I appreciate for your participation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you solve the issue? has the same at existing project on new mac